# $_SESSION variable passing into a class

Tags: php, session

In my first .php files I have:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['ProdType1'] = $_GET['ProdType'];

echo "session Product type = " . $_SESSION['ProdType1'];
require_once("./include/fgcontactform.php");
```

`$_SESSION['ProdType1']` is set correctly.

In `fgcontactform.php` I have the following:

```
echo "Prod typefg = " . $_SESSION['ProdType1'];
```

`$_SESSION['ProdType1']` is set correctly.

```
class FGContactForm
{
    function ExtraInfoToMail()
    {
        $ret_str='';

//echo "Prod type in func = " . $_SESSION['ProdType1'];

        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $p1 = $_SESSION['ProdType1'];

        $ret_str = "<div class='label'>IP address of the submitter: </div><div class='value'>$ip</div>\n";
        $ret_str .= "<div class='label'>Product Type: </div><divclass='value'>$p1</div>\n";

        return $ret_str;
    }
```

`$p1` is null and so is `$_SESSION['ProdType1']`.

Any help would be great.

Comment: You show us a class, but how does this class method get called?

Comment: Add `if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) { session_start();}` in the `ExtraInfoToMail` method

Comment: `$_GET['ProdType']` must be empty. How do you fill this value?

Comment: Do also `if(isset($_GET['ProdType'])) $_SESSION['ProdType1'] = $_GET['ProdType'];`, to prevent not set empty as @Lars Mertens says

Comment: ProdType is passed from a html thru a url.  the value is set and shows in the echo commands .  the class is called with $formproc = new FGContactForm();

Comment: if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) { session_start(); cause the function to lockup

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions`session_start()` should only be at the very top of the page.

Comment: @Spencer Wieczorek `of the page` means of the file? And it MUST not at the top of anything. You can one on request also open and close session if you want to or application needs that for wahtever. So whats the point here? I and my comments are just a quick fix hint :)

Comment: @Mark Ledford `function to lockup ` And that means what?

Comment: the function stops and the .php does nothing else.  I have to reload the webpage.